# Avoid to return viewstate in some cases

Tags: c#, asp.net, optimization, viewstate

I'm looking for a solution to reduce the amount of transferred data between client/server in an ASP.NET project, I noticed that during the postback there is a case in which some not necessary data  are sent to the client, the situation is this:

The user click a button in a popup on the client, the client send all the data in the viewstate to the server, at this point there are 2 possible ways:
1 - some operations occur and the data in the viewstate must return to the client;
2 - some operations occur and, at this point, I'm not interested to resend the viewstate to the client but I want only close the popup

How is possibile in the second case avoid to resend useless data to the client?

Sorry for my poor english, I hope to be clear

Answer (score 0):

You can set EnableViewState to false, either for the whole page, or selectively for some controls on the page.